# Difference between environment variables get loaded when using sudo linux

Tags: linux, kerberos, sudo, su

Hello I would like to understand the differences w.r.t env that gets setup using sudo su - vs just a sudo su.

User already a part of sudoers

Not able use few kerberos commands when I use just sudo su.

Answer (score 0):

A look in the manual page for the `su` command showed the following:

```
   -, -l, --login
          Start the shell as a login shell with an environment similar
          to a real login:

             o      clears all the environment variables except TERM

             o      initializes the environment variables HOME, SHELL,
                    USER, LOGNAME, and PATH

             o      changes to the target user's home directory

             o      sets argv[0] of the shell to '-' in order to make
                    the shell a login shell
```

So, if you use `sudo su -` the above mentioned variables are erased and filled with information according to your new user (root or another).

Maybe some needed environmental variables are set for your root user?
Unfortunately, I haven't worked with kerberos yet.

Hope I helped you a bit.